# How to check whether a scroll bar is populated for a plain text area?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a free text area which does not have any scroll bar. But when I enter characters in to the text field scroll bars are introduced. How to check this scrollbar is present or not using selenium webdriver.

Comment: May be this can help you : http://www.testingdiaries.com/selenium-verify-scrollbar-webdriver/

Comment: Thanks for the input. But this for a web page. I need to check for a text area ( It's a web element)

Comment: When you focus-out of the text area, do the scroll bars disappear? Clarifying: does the scrollbar only get introduced while you're typing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to execute JavaScript to determine that, something like this (replace the query with something that returns your specific textarea):

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
boolean scrollBarPresent = (boolean) js.executeScript(
        "var element = document.querySelector('textarea'); " + 
        "return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;");
```